# How to remove special characters from strings

Tags: ruby, regex

I have one line with libraries names, and I need to have a list of clean names without special characters.

```
 include ':app', ':Android-RSS-Reader-Library-master', ':facebook',
 ':Forecast', ':headerListView', ':library-sliding-menu',
 /*':PanoramaGL',*/ ':stripe', ':ProgressWheel-master', ':UIL_library',
 ':volley'
```

This my function but it gives me names with special characters. How I can remove them?

```
def getLib

  File.open('./out.txt', 'w') do |f|
    File.foreach('./settings.gradle') do |line|
      # directory_name = line[/':([^']+)'/, 1]
      directory_name = line.split(/\'\:/)

      f.puts directory_name
    end 
  end 
end
```

The result is:

```
include  app',  Android-RSS-Reader-Library-master',  facebook',  Forecast',  headerListView',  library-sliding-menu', /* PanoramaGL',*/ stripe',  ProgressWheel-master',  UIL_library',  volley'
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Read before commenting :I had one line with librairies names, and I need to have a list of items using Ruby.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What output do you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want an array of items, listed in your file via a comma, you can do it this way:

```
line.scan(/'(:.+?)'/).flatten
# => [":app", ":Android-RSS-Reader-Library-master", ":facebook", ":Forecast", ":headerListView", ":library-sliding-menu", ":PanoramaGL", ":stripe", ":ProgressWheel-master", ":UIL_library", ":volley"]
```

If you don't need a colon in the name, just move it out of the braces:

```
line.scan(/':(.+?)'/).flatten
=> ["app", "Android-RSS-Reader-Library-master", "facebook", "Forecast", "headerListView", "library-sliding-menu", "PanoramaGL", "stripe", "ProgressWheel-master", "UIL_library", "volley"]
```

Comment: Thank's Sir, you are the best !